# BufferedReader and Scanner: limit the number of input characters

Tags: java

Here are two simple examples:

Here is the first -

```
...
BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
   new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in) );

String string = new String ();
try {
   string = bufferedReader.readLine();
} сatch (IOException ioe) {
   //TODO Auto-generated catch block
   ioe.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(string);
...
```

And this-

```
...
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String string = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println(string);
...
```

For example, i need only `100` characters and i want to stop user input, when the number of characters will be equals 100. Then output the string.

How to set this limit using `API` of class `BufferedReader` and `Scanner`?

Comment: WHen you say "stop user input" what do you want to happen?  Do you want to disable the user's keyboard at this point or just truncate the input? What would happen if you didn't do this? i.e. what problem are you trying to prevent?

Comment: The console is line buffered, you won't get anything until the user hits Enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to prevent the user inputting data until ENTER is pressed but you could limit the amount of characters consumed by the read:

```
char[] buffer = new char[100];
int charsRead = bufferedReader.read(buffer);
```

and

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String string = scanner.findInLine(".{100}");
```