# displaying only 5 digits in account and password java

Tags: java

I need user to only input 5 digits for acc number and password i try this one but i can still run with more than 5 digits ..

```
public static void login() throws IllegalLoginException {

    int acc, password;
    System.out.println("Welcome!");
    System.out.print("Enter your account number: ");
    acc = in.nextInt();

   if (acc > 010000 && acc < 9999){

          throw new IllegalLoginException("from Exception: Account number not enough 5 digits");

    }
    System.out.print("Enter your password number: ");
    password = in.nextInt();

    if (password >= 12345 && password <= 9999) {

          throw new IllegalLoginException("from Exception: 5 Digits password required!");
    }
    System.out.println("\nHello there, " + acc);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BufferedReader and Scanner: limit the number of input characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243991/bufferedreader-and-scanner-limit-the-number-of-input-characters)

Comment: The console is line buffered, you won't get anything until the user hits Enter.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void login() throws IllegalLoginException {

    int acc, password;
    System.out.println("Welcome!");
    System.out.print("Enter your account number: ");
    acc = in.nextInt();

   if (acc == null || acc.trim.length()!=5){

          throw new IllegalLoginException("from Exception: Account number must be 5 digits long");

    }
    System.out.print("Enter your password number: ");
    password = in.nextInt();

    if (password == null || password.trim.length()!=5) {

          throw new IllegalLoginException("from Exception: 5 Digits password required!");
    }
    System.out.println("\nHello there, " + acc);
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer. Question is how to restrict the input not validate it after the input is entered.